# ArcGIS WMS in Android. ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: wms, java, android, arcgis-android

I have a simple Android application that used the ArcGIS SDK to render a map, that works fine, but when I try to use a WMSLayer to render over my map, it generates me an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and I don't get why.

My code:
MainActivity.java

```
package wmstest.com.wmstest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.esri.android.map.MapView;
import com.esri.android.map.ogc.WMSLayer;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    MapView mMapView;

    // Called when the activity is first created.
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);

        try {
            String wmsURL = "http://srv1.nanoterra.ro:8080/geoserver/wms" +
                    "?SERVICE=WMS" +
                    "&VERSION=1.3.0" +
                    "&REQUEST=GetMap" +
                    "&FORMAT=image%2Fpng" +
                    "&TRANSPARENT=true" +
                    "&LAYERS=craiova_site" +
                    "&TILED=true" +
                    "&time_=1424422953367" +
                    "&WIDTH=256" +
                    "&HEIGHT=256" +
                    "&CRS=EPSG%3A31700" +
                    "&STYLES=&BBOX=312735.5839256644%2C403135.7136541791%2C313346.39561301924%2C403746.52534153394";
            WMSLayer wmsLayer = new WMSLayer(wmsURL);
            mMapView.addLayer(wmsLayer);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("WMSTEST", e + "");
        }
    }

}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <com.esri.android.map.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        mapoptions.MapType="Topo"
        mapoptions.center="34.056215, -117.195668"
        mapoptions.ZoomLevel="16" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Stacktrace:

```
6835-6899/wmstest.com.wmstest E/ArcGIS﹕ url =http://srv1.nanoterra.ro:8080/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=craiova_site&TILED=true&time_=1424422953367&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A31700&STYLES=&BBOX=312735.5839256644%2C403135.7136541791%2C313346.39561301924%2C403746.52534153394
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
            at com.esri.core.internal.tasks.e.a.b.<init>(SourceFile:61)
            at com.esri.core.internal.tasks.e.a.b.<init>(SourceFile:43)
            at com.esri.android.map.ogc.WMSLayer.initLayer(SourceFile:382)
            at com.esri.android.map.ogc.WMSLayer$1.run(SourceFile:206)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:390)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: I've setted the wmsLayer with an ArcGIS basemap. The issue is that they have not the same spatial reference so, do you know if it's possible to change the WMS spatial reference whithin the code? And, if possible, how? This is my code: public class ArteixoActivity extends AppCompatActivity { MapView mMapView; WMSLayer wmsLayer; String wmsURL; @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.activity_second); mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map); MapOptions options = new MapOptions(MapOptions.MapType.SATELLITE, 43.3035

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because you are not setting the `wmsURL` correctly.  The API expects the URL to conform to the server type, e.g. **http://srv1.nanoterra.ro:8080/geoserver/wms**, then use the methods on `WMSLayer` to configure the layer.  Below I offer code that loads the layer:

```
    // set up the sml url
    wmsURL = "http://srv1.nanoterra.ro:8080/geoserver/wms";
    wmsLayer = new WMSLayer(wmsURL);
    wmsLayer.setImageFormat("image/png");
    // available layers
    String[] visibleLayers = {"craiova_site"};
    wmsLayer.setVisibleLayer(visibleLayers);
    wmsLayer.setTransparent(true);
    // add layer to map
    mMapView.addLayer(wmsLayer);
```